# Filtered Questions email notifications have stopped working for me

Tags: bug, notifications, filtering, email

I have a filter set up that is set to email me every 15 minutes. It has been working for me, and I was getting notified. Today I happened to see a question that should have been caught by the filter. Looking at the filter, is indeed being caught, but I did not receive an e-mail.

I checked my junk mail and it was not in there. I am receiving other messages. Since I don't have access to my mail server operations (google apps), I can't look further on my end.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Should I use the contact form? The form doesn't appear to have options  for this kind of thing, so I thought it would be more appropriate to ask here first. Thanks!

The filter in question: https://stackexchange.com/filters/147108/dsc

Answer (score 1):

**Just after** posting this, I received the email. I analyzed the header and it does look like there was a 2 hour delay from when the message was generated until it was received/accepted by google. I can't tell which end that was due to.

Maybe someone at SE will find [this header analysis useful](http://mxtoolbox.com/Public/Tools/EmailHeaders.aspx?huid=6c8a7198-7ac5-4c64-be5c-4bf4283856f7).

**Edit:** I had another instance today, [still seems to be a ~2 hour delay](http://mxtoolbox.com/Public/Tools/EmailHeaders.aspx?huid=c360c0ad-1dc5-4350-b0ee-9f901b72b94b).